# Who is Baba Sola?

Tags: noor

In the novella *Noor*, when Ao and DNA first enter the Red Eye, they meet a man who goes by the name of Baba Sola. Baba Sola is described as being Caucasian, and seemingly being some sort of wizard or sorcerer, with DNA making various claims about him, including that he moves backwards in time.

The last bit seems like a possible reference to Merlin, who famously lived backward in *The Once and Future King*. However, it could be a coincidence, and religious or mythological characters in Okorafor's works are almost all from West African folklore and religion, more so than the British Isles. Okorafar also has a number of other works, so Baba Sola could also be from one of them.

Is Baba Sola a character in folklore or in any of Okorafor's other works? If so, who?